# What happens when two threads try to modify/access the same key in HashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading

In concurrent environment `ConcurrentHashMap` should be used. But what did java promise for normal HashMap?

```
Map map = new HashMap();

// thread 1
map.put("a", 1)

// thread 2
map.put("a", 2)
```

when try to get value by `map.get("a")`, will I be promised that the map will not broken and the return value must in `1` or `2`?

Comment: No. The map may be broken, don't do that.

Comment: If you abuse any code declared to be not thread-safe such as [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), there is no promise of behavior, the results are not predictable. Given the clarity of the `HashMap` documentation, and given that you know of [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), your Question does not make any sense.

Comment: Same as if you're inviting a grizzly bear to a fancy dress party... you have no way of knowing what will happen and it will most probably not be pretty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood, the question is about what happens in a concurrent scenario and not if the HashMap is suitable or not (what is widely known as not suitable).

The best way to realize what kind of problems can be found in a very undesirable scenario like that is to analyse [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java). For example, in the openjdk 1.6 implementation:

```
public V More ...put(K key, V value) {
     if (key == null)
         return putForNullKey(value);
     int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
     int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
             V oldValue = e.value;
             e.value = value;
             e.recordAccess(this);
             return oldValue;
         }
    }

     modCount++;
     addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
     return null;
 }
```

In the absence o synchronisation mechanism in this method and in the attributes, one or more of the following problems can occurs:

1) non-deterministic return

The line:

```
return oldValue;
```

results for thread 1 can be the old value (before thread 1 and 2 calls), can be 2 or null. Its dependes if the Thread 2 addEntry(hash, key, value, i) completely rans or not. The same problem with thread 2, of course.

2) undetermined index and duplicated keys

```
int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
```

depends over the table.length. So, depending if there exist a previous value for this hash or not, the i index can diverge for both calls (depending on the execution of addEntry(hash, key, value, i) in the another thread.

3) Broken size and consistence

It is expected that successive calls of put("a",...) do not change the size of the map (at least after the first call when there is no entry for key "a"). But, depending on the [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) of the two threads, the map size consistence can become broken, i.e, the size of the [keyset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) is different of the size of map size. Other variables used to hash the key, as modCount can become inconsistent broken future calls of put and get.

So, how was properly said in the question commentaries, the use of a Map in a concurrent scenario is fully disencoraged due the unexpected behaviour and damage to the inner structure.

Answer (score 3):

Hashmaps are not thread safe, there's no guarantee what would happen.
It depends on the sequence of execution of the threads.

Comment: The last sentence here seems to imply that the behaviour is either one or the other of the alternatives proposed by the OP, which isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

Multi-thread access to HashMap not in reading mode can cause undefined behavior.

Use synchronized construction `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())`