# How is it possible to get duplicate keys in map

Tags: java, groovy, jvm

Sometimes my java/groovy application behaves strange: there is a map that is not null and has values in it, but when I'm trying to get value by exact same key that I see when I log that map I'm getting null. The most strange part is that map in log has duplicate keys.

Restarting application solves the problem, but I'm interested in how is that even possible.

I have this code:

```
def mainField = typeSettings?.mainField != null 
    ? typeSettings?.mainField 
    : classSettings.mainField
logger.info("${typeSettings}\n ${classSettings}\n ${classSettings.mainField}")
```

I'm sure that `classSettings` is not `null`

And here's what I see in the log:

```
null
[
    iconsField:[], 
    mainField:[
        [
            code:portalCard, showTitle:false, pages:[card]
        ], 
        [
            code:portalAddForm, showTitle:false, pages:[addForm]
        ]
    ], 
    footer:[showNegotDate:true, showPlanDate:true], 
    footer:[showNegotDate:true, showPlanDate:true]
]
null
```

But it's pretty clear that `mainField` is present in the map and even more there are somehow two duplicate keys `footer` in that map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is concurrent modification of that map which is mentioned here: [What happens when two threads try to modify/access the same key in HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902323/what-happens-when-two-threads-try-to-modify-access-the-same-key-in-hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

E.g. GStrings can do that (they print the same, but they hash different):

```
groovy:000> [footer: 1, ("${"footer"}"): 2]
===> [footer:1, footer:2]
```

If you want to debug things like that, it's usually better to use `.inspect()` instead of just a `.toString()` (might not help in any case, but here it actually gives a clue):

```
groovy:000> [footer: 1, ("${"footer"}"): 2].inspect()
===> ['footer':1, footer:2]
```

In the end, you have to look at the types or the hash codes:

```
groovy:000> [footer: 1, ("${"footer"}"): 2].keySet()*.getClass()
===> [class java.lang.String, class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl]
groovy:000> [footer: 1, ("${"footer"}"): 2].keySet()*.hashCode()
===> [-1268861541, -1268861504]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but It's not the case, unfortunately. I'm pretty sure that both keys are simple strings.

Comment: "pretty sure" aint "sure" ;).  Maybe something modifies the map while printing it?  is it shared?

Comment: I even called `classSettings.keySet()*.hashCode()` and I saw same hash codes

Comment: Seems like the problem is concurrent modification of that map which is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902323/what-happens-when-two-threads-try-to-modify-access-the-same-key-in-hashmap